# Why are my images exported to flickr at a lower resolution when I asked for "Actual size"?

Tags: aperture, flickr

When I export a bunch of images to Flickr by using the built-in share to flickr, I see the images getting exported but they all appear as max 1024 pixels on either side. I did select "Actual size" when exporting so it should use the full resolution. And I think it did work fine in a previous export.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wait a little longer. What happens is that it starts by uploading 1024-sized images, and then later replaces them with high-resolution versione. So if you check flickr while it is still working you will see the lower-resolution versions but wait and reload and it will be high-resolution.

Comment: I just realised I have this problem when I went to download a photo from my flickr set (b/c I didn't have my external hard drive handy). It seems even older albums (from a couple of months ago) have lower resolution photos! Is there some other syncing feature or setting I'm missing? I might have to go back to the old FlickrExport app I used to use until this spring. But I'm not sure what to do about the hundreds of photos I've uploaded since starting using the built in Aperture Flickr uploading feature - those appear to be lower resolution than actual.